# How to run php code in gedit using External Tools plugin?

Tags: php, shell, console, gedit

I've tried this code in External Tools with actual document as input. But it doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/php -r
```

Syntax check works as expected

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/php -l
```

Outputs either error message or "No syntax errors detected"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the external tools, set the "Input" to "Current document" and the command is just php (no options):

```
php
```

The output in the bottom pane will be the output of your script. Just keep in mind that this is only going to work for local files.

Edit: screenshots...

[image]

[image: Running PHP from Gedit]

Comment: Thanks. The problem is not in php executable path. Syntax checking works just fine. The problem is probably in that the actual document is not sent to executable or is sent in a way executable doesn't understand with -r flag. All I get is a message which appears when invalid input is sent to PHP: `code`Usage: php [options] [-f] <file>...`/code`

Comment: The external tools is going to send the filename, not the contents of the file. So you do not want to use the -r option. So use just /usr/bin/php and leave off the -r. The working directory for the PHP script will be the same as the document so keep that in mind as far as includes.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I had to define PHP path as well, **/opt/lampp/bin/php**

Answer (score 1):

You can also one of the many Gedit [keywords](https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins/Snippets).

```
$$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_PATH
$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_URI
```

Comment: That link to keywords is broken, [this alternative](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/Plugins/ExternalTools) comes close I guess.